# Get kafka consumer lag as a prometheus metric

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, spring-kafka

hi i have a consumer with multiple listeners with concurrency as 3. Each listener consume one topic. I'm trying to get the consumer lag of the containers in prometheus metric endpint. I checked the default metrics and only the listener related success and failure count and sum are available. Is there any option that i can get consumer lag exposed as a prometheus metric ?

**EDIT**

I'm using spring-kafka and with that in the documentation it says i can simple get the listener and broker related metrics (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#monitoring-listener-performance). What i did was call the prometheus endpoint like `myUrl/prometheus` and i was able to see the listener logs.

So is there a way to view consumer lag like that?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your metrics endpoint output? Lag should be there

Comment: You need to get **JMX Consumer Metrics**, nothing related to Spring. Any Java Kafka consumer client has lag as JXM Bean. There's also other ways to do it, as mentioned at https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-consumer-lag ; but [micrometer source code](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaConsumerMetrics.java#L103) shows lag is definitely available.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Spring does not provide an easy way to do this (see [Monitoring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/#micrometer) documentation for more details).
You can use some of the existing solutions to eliminate dependency on your consumers implementations. For example:

1. [Kafka Lag Exporter](https://github.com/seglo/kafka-lag-exporter).

It provides a metrics like `kafka_consumergroup_group_lag` with labels: `cluster_name`, `group`, `topic`, `partition`, `member_host`, `consumer_id`, `client_id`.
It is easy to set up and can run anywhere, but it provides features to run easily on Kubernetes clusters.

2. [Kafka Exporter](https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter)

It provides more different kafka metrics. For the lag, it has an example of the `kafka_consumergroup_lag` metric with the labels: `consumergroup`, `partition`, `topic`

Comment: Burrow is more commonly used than these options, IMO, but yes Spring Micrometer **does** have a lag metric for consumers

Comment: @OneCricketeer i checked Spring micrometer metrics and i couldn't find any. How can i check it in Spring Micrometer ?

Comment: @Dushan Edit your question to include how you checked.